# Function to generate random date from period

Tags: plsql, oracle12c

I would like to generate in oracle sql random date ('yy-mm-dd') from function. I made something like this:

```
create or replace function fn_random_date (v_min date, v_max date) return date AS
v_result date; 
begin   
SELECT dbms_random.value (TO_CHAR(DATE v_min),TO_CHAR(DATE v_max)) into v_result from dual;
return v_result;
end;
```

I know that is wrong but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I read that post but it does not help me.

Comment: Why not? Please can you explain what you different from what that answer does?

Comment: I do not know what is "J" in  that
DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2000-01-01','J')
And i would like to store my date.
I would like to have min_date and max_date and generate from them.

Comment: In can't get the point. If you copy the select query from the post I linked into your procedure, I believe you exactly get what you need. About the meaning of 'J', have a look at [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A)

Comment: The Accepted Answer in the linked thread may be correct, but it's quite convoluted. If you must generate a random date between `dt1` and `dt2`, use: `dt1 + dbms_random.value(0, dt2 - dt1)`. And then truncate if you need a "pure date" (which in Oracle and in PL/SQL means "with the time-of-day set to midnight, 00:00:00). Note that a `date` expression does not have a format, like the ('yy-mm-dd') in your question; that part of the question is nonsensical.